# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" in to-do app

Tags: html, json, ajax

Working on a simple to do app.  Expected behavior is user types in something in the text box, hits create, and it appends to the list.

What happens instead is when you click create, nothing happens.  There are no errors returned in the terminal so I was confused for a while until I looked in the Chrome console.  It shows this:
[image: error messsage]

I'll link to the full code on GitHub here: https://github.com/zemelb/todoapp/tree/master

But this is the part I believe is causing the issue:

```
fetch('/todos/create', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    // body is whatever the user has typed into the description field
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        'description': document.getElementById('description').value
                    }),
                    // let the server know you're sending JSON
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                })
```

In the similar questions I've seen asked about this, people say that it's likely because it's trying to get data from an object that doesn't exist yet.  But in this case I'm pretty sure it exists, unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Never assume your selectors will find the elements you think they will. Your error means `document.getElementById('description')` is not finding a matching element. Thus you're effectively asking for the `value` property of `null`.

Comment: So how would I assure that it finds it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
<input type="text" name="description">
```

to:

```
<input type="text" id="description">
```